# Finding contradiction in mysql table

Tags: mysql, join, multiple-columns, distinct, data-cleaning

I have a table of 5000 rows with 9 columns in it. And I am in a process of data cleaning. So I need a query to return only rockets names that are `Active` and `Retired` at the same time

Below is a sample of 2 columns that I am working on :

| Rocket | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Sputnik | Retired |
| Sputnik | Active |
| Vanguard | Retired |
| Juno I | Retired |
| Sputnik | Retired |
| Vostok | Retired |

So the result should be like this :

| Rocket | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Sputnik | Retired |
| Sputnik | Active |

I tried distinct, self join, group by but I failed to achieve my goal.

-- This query will return every distinct rows:

> select distinct(concat(rocket,'_', rocketstatus)) as BB
>
> from space.test_1
>
> group by bb

-- This query will return nothing:

> select a.rocket, a.rocketstatus from space.test_1 b
>
> join space.test_1 a on a.id = b.id
>
> where a.rocketstatus not in (select b.rocketstatus from space.test_1 b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this variant will suit you

```
select distinct a.Rocket,b.Status from 
    (
      select Rocket,count(distinct Status) as cnt from test_1 group by Rocket
    ) a inner join test_1 b on b.Rocket=a.Rocket where a.cnt>1
```